# How does a vector defined with a fixed size is accessed?

Tags: c++, vector

Here is a part of code extracted from a cpp file. I am unable to understand/track how this code works. The vector here is defined with a fixed size and the while accessing it, there are two square brackets used for accessing a two dimensional array.

```
#include <iostream>
#include<vector> 
#include<stdio.h>
#define FOR(i,a,b) for(int i=a;i<b;i++)
#define REP(i,n) FOR(i,0,n)
#define PB push_back
using namespace std;

int main()
{
vector<int> v[10];
int a,b;
REP(i,5)
    {
        scanf("%d%d",&a,&b);

        a--;
        b--;
        v[a].PB(b);
        v[b].PB(a);
    }

    for(int n=0;n<5;n++){
    REP(i,v[n].size())
    {
        cout<<v[n][i]<<" ";
    }
    cout<<endl;
    }
return 0;
}
```

In the above program if I give the following inputs:(underscore is just to distinguish separate inputs)

```
4 5
2 3
6 8
1 2
8 6
```

I get the following outputs:

```
1
2 0
1
4
3
```

Can someone explain to me how is this happening?
Thanks

Comment: `v` is an array of `10` `std::vector`. `v[n][i]` is the ith element of the nth vector in the array.

Comment: Don't use macros to redefine the language. It doesn't make code more readable, quite the opposite.

Comment: I also recommend that you format the input and output as code, to make it easier to read. And please show us the *expected* output, not only the actual output. Oh, and please try to reformat the code to use consistent indentation, as that also helps yo make it more readable.

Comment: Finally, please [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). That should hopefully help quite a lot with your understanding of the code.

Comment: *The vector here is defined with a fixed size*  -- There is no such thing in your program.  As a matter of fact, there is no such thing as a `std::vector` with a fixed size.  A vector is resizable.  A `std::array<T>` is fixed in size.

Comment: Thanks, @Blaze that is helpful. It seems I can trace it now.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude sorry for writting in such bad format. I am new here so I don't really know how to post question properly and also vector for is new for me so I didn't really know how things work in this. Anyways, I am learning to debug. Thanks.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, thanks. I got that, now I can trace it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I agree with all the comments to your question, about formatting, debugging, macros, etc. But I will try to explain to you as a beginner what is going on in the code.

This is how you would define a vector of int:

```
vector<int> v;
```

This will define an ***array*** of 10 vectors of int:

```
vector<int> v[10];
```

That is what your program is doing: It is defining an array that contains 10 vectors.

When accessing the data with this:

```
v[n][i]
```

What is happening is that you are taking the n'th vector in the array, and getting the i'th element in that vector.

When you do this:

```
v[a].PB(b);
```

you are taking the a'th vector in the array, and adding the number b to the end of it as a new element in that vector.

After that, you just have to follow the logic of the code carefully. I'd advise using a debugger to step through the code and examine the values of the variables while doing this.

But basically, the user is entering values which the program then adds to the vectors in a complicated way (with no protection for the user entering values out of range -- very dangerous). Then  the program prints out all the values of the first 5 vectors.